# make collapsable to parent dataTable in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, datatable

I have two data tables in my JSF page, I want to make it collapsible where an inner table would be the content of outer data table. upon click on the title of the parent table, it should be a toggle like collapsible.

```
                                <h:dataTable id="myDataTable"
                                value="#{dataEntryFormController.sampleList}" var="o"
                                binding="#{table}" varStatus="record">

                                <h:column>

                                    <h:dataTable id="myDataTable2" value="#{o}" var="sample"
                                         binding="#{table2}">
                                        <h:column>
                                            <h:inputText value="#{sample.sampleKey}" rendered="#{sample.editable}" />
                                            <h:outputText value="#{sample.sampleKey}" rendered="#{not sample.editable}" />
                                            <h:outputText value="&lt;br/&gt;" escape="false" />
                                            <h:outputText value="&lt;br/&gt;" escape="false" />
                                        </h:column>


                                        <h:column>
                                            <h:inputText value="#{sample.sampleValue}" rendered="#{sample.editable}" />
                                            <h:outputText value="#{sample.sampleValue}" rendered="#{not sample.editable}" />
                                            <h:outputText value="&lt;br/&gt;" escape="false" />
                                            <h:outputText value="&lt;br/&gt;" escape="false" />
                                        </h:column>


                                        <h:column>
                                            <h:commandButton value="Remove"
                                                action="#{dataEntryFormController.deleteRecord(sample,table.rowIndex,table2.rowIndex)}"
                                                > 
                                            </h:commandButton>
                                            <h:commandButton value="Edit"
                                                action="#{dataEntryFormController.editAction(sample,table.rowIndex,table2.rowIndex)}" 
                                                rendered="#{not sample.editable}">
                                            </h:commandButton>
                                            <h:outputText value="&lt;br/&gt;" escape="false" />
                                        </h:column>
                                    </h:dataTable>
                                </h:column>

                            </h:dataTable>
```

Comment: Something like this? https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/expansion.xhtml

Comment: Did not specify `JSF` implementation and/or component library to be used...

Comment: how can I do it without using primefaces?

Comment: I do not know. PrimeFaces has this `<p:rowExpansion>` component, that is doing just that, but it is not a "built in" `JSF` component, so if you know what component library are you using, if any, then look at their documentation for similar component...

Comment: I am using only jquery and JSF, but when I put data table into divs it not work inside that collapsible divs.

Comment: Try to inspect the generated code in a browser, and add collapsible CSS to the generated HTML tags.